# Turn keys and values into a string javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to concatenate the keys and values of an object into a string with certain rules when joining each string. The object looks like this:

```
{ sm: "column", md: "row", lg: "row"}
```

Ideally I would like turn it into string resembling this:

```
"sm-column md-row lg-row".
```

I'm struggling with a way to join the arrays with different rules. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```js
const direction = { sm: 'column', md: 'row', lg: 'row'}

const result = Object.entries(direction).flat().join(" ")

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. Just one small change is needed. Instead of using `.flat()` to put the keys and values together in one big array, first use `map` to join each inner array with a "-" before joining the inner arrays with a space. (Note I used a template literal with an anonymous function to do the inner join here, but I could easily have used `.join("-")` instead. Neither is better than the others, it was just the first thing that occurred to me.)

```js
const direction = { sm: 'column', md: 'row', lg: 'row'}

const result = Object.entries(direction).map(([key, value]) => `${key}-${value}`).join(" ")

console.log(result)
```